# How to apply class to container that's children have the required two class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hard to explain, but here is an example:

```
<div>
  <span class='first'>text</span>
  <span>text</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>text</span>
  <span class='second'>text</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class='first'>text</span>
  <span class='second'>text</span>
</div>
```

I want to apply a class to the div, that has **both** `first` and `second` classed childs.

So this would be the modified html:

```
<div>
  <span class='first'>text</span>
  <span>text</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>text</span>
  <span class='second'>text</span>
</div>

<div class='addedClass'>
  <span class='first'>text</span>
  <span class='second'>text</span>
</div>
```

I could make it by labelling divs with `data` attributes, but that doesn't seems the best way, I believe there is a way with jquery's engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try chaining your jQuery selectors like so:

```
$("div").has(".first").has(".second").addClass("addedClass");
```

So essentially you're saying, select the div that has a child element with class "first" as well as one with class "second".

Example: http://codepen.io/JasonGraham/pen/xOdRpz

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`:has`**](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector

> *Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector*

```js
$('div:has(span.first):has(span.second)').addClass('has')
```

```css
.has {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class='first'>text</span>
  <span>text</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>text</span>
  <span class='second'>text</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class='first'>text</span>
  <span class='second'>text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way is to [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the selected elements:

```js
$(function () {
  $('div').filter(function(index, element) {
    return ($(this).children('.first').length == 1 && $(this).children('.second').length == 1);
  }).addClass('addedClass');
});
```

```css
.addedClass {
  background: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <span class='first'>text</span>
    <span>text</span>
</div>

<div>
    <span>text</span>
    <span class='second'>text</span>
</div>

<div>
    <span class='first'>text</span>
    <span class='second'>text</span>
</div>
```

Because you are looking for [next adjacent selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/) elements you may use the shortest form:

```
$('div').has('span.first+span.second').addClass('addedClass');
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('div').has('span.first+span.second').addClass('addedClass');
});
```

```css
.addedClass {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <span class='first'>text</span>
    <span>text</span>
</div>

<div>
    <span>text</span>
    <span class='second'>text</span>
</div>

<div>
    <span class='first'>text</span>
    <span class='second'>text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: May be `$('div').filter(function(index, element) {
  return $(this).children('.first').length == 1 && $(this).children('.second').length == 1;
});`

Comment: @Rayon Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Just saw another post with using the CSS selector '+'

you can also use '~' it depends on whether you need the very next one (+)
or somewhere adjacent (~)

$('.first ~.second').parent().addClass('addedClass');